# string to double validation c# please answer

Tags: c#, string, validation, numerical, typeconverter

ok so I am building a program in WPF format.
as you know wpf's inputs are usually **string**, to turn those into **double** first I need to validate if those string fit and then to proceed and convert them.
the problem is in the validation, I have done the part in the validation that is checking if the **string.IsNullOrEmpty** but the thing I could not do is validate if the answer is completely not convertable... let me show an example because some strings that are not completely numeric are still should be accepted for example:

"sadasdaasd" - not accepted (obviously)

"8945a4554" - not accepted (there is an 'a' in the middle)

"3519" - accepted

"12.55" - accepted

"-3/4" - accepted and the value should be converted to double as (-3) divided by (4). so '/' is accepted and it splits the string by 2 and then converts it to double as first part/ second part.

I have been trying to do this validation all day and still have not succeeded, I have tried searching the web for some input validation, some said that I need to use **double.TryParse(string, out double)** but this function does not work with the '/' split that i wanted. so please help me!!!

Comment: If the only case that breaks `TryParse` is fractions, can't you just parse those out, `TryParse` the numerator and denominator, and use the calculation?

Comment: TryParse is the answer, but you'll need to do it in three steps. First, split the string (if needed), and then try to parse both sides (or just one if there aren't two), and finally do the calculation if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by parsing your string via regex (q: is "-3*4" acceptable as -3 times 4?).  Basically you're looking for a match on a regex which is kind of like this (this works on -3/4, you'd want to test it further and modify if multiplication is allowed):  `-?\d+[/]\d+`

If you find that match, parse out your string with `string.Split('/')` which will give you an array of strings.  TryParse each of those and do the math.

If there is not a match, use TryParse (as recommended previously).  That will either succeed (3519, 12.55 in your examples) or fail (sadasdaasd, 8945a4554 in your examples).

Note: you could also use string.Contains('/'), but then you have to check to see if it holds more than one slash (unless such a thing is allowed- in which case you'll need to revisit that regex).

Comment: can you write this to me like exactly like it should be in the program, like exact code... and also please add the multiplication. and you can skip the part that splits up the string if those two do exist because i've already done it

Comment: No.  There are plenty of questions here about how to use Regex in C#, along with string manipulations.  Try some things first.  If those don't work, post a specific question about what isn't working along with some code.